# C# - Converting from bits to Int32 generates wrong value

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, binary, integer, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an array of `int` values (each value representing a bit) to its representation as an `Int32` object.

I have the following code:

```
//0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_0000_1111 = 15
int[] numberData = new int[]
{
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
};

//We convert our int[] to a bool[]
bool[] numberBits = numberData.Select(s => { return s == 0 ? false : true; }).ToArray();

//We generate a bit array from our bool[]
BitArray bits = new BitArray(numberBits);

//We copy all our bits to a byte[]
byte[] numberBytes = new byte[sizeof(int)];
bits.CopyTo(numberBytes, 0);

//We convert our byte[] to an int
int number = BitConverter.ToInt32(numberBytes, 0);
```

However, after executing this code, the value of `number` is **-268435456**.

Why does this happen?

Comment: I don't think there's an overflow. BitArray has a total of 32 bits, which are being copied to a byte[] of size 4

Comment: Note: this is a very long winded way of creating an integer from bits. Much better ways of doing this exist (which also don't suffer from the "endianness" issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bit order is incorrect. `-268435456` as a 32-bit integer is `11110000 00000000 00000000 00000000`, which, as you can see, is exactly opposite what you wanted.

Just reverse your `numberBits` array before converting it to an `Int32`.

Alternatively, you could make `numberData` have the correct order and then never do any reversing.

Your code is working exactly how you wrote it. In `numberData[0]` is `0`, `numberData[1]` is `0`, ..., and `numberData[31]` is `1`. This will cause bit 0 of your result to be `0`, bit 1 to be `0`, ..., and bit 31 to be `1`.

Comment: I have reversed `numberData` and now `number` is returning **251658240** :(

Comment: @MatiCicero I've just tried your code, reversing the bits (1,1,1,1,0,0,....,0,0), and the answer comes out as 15...

Comment: My bad, it's in fact returning 15. This solution is correct

Comment: Confirmed. I did an `Array.Reverse(numberData);` and it does come out as 15.